Would a homogeneous rod on a fulcrum oscillate or remain at rest after displacement?
If I take a homogeneous rod, put it on a fulcrum, push one side down in a controlled way and release very carefully won't the rod just stay at rest in that new position? ChatGPT says that it would oscillate, but I can't wrap my head around why that would be the case. I have the feeling that their answer is wrong, but I can't prove my answer either.


Generally speaking, when it comes to physics, ChatGPT is almost always wrong.

If the rod has insignificant thickness, is uniform, and is perfectly balanced about the fulcrum when level, then the weights of the parts on either side of the fulcrum will be equal no matter what the angle of tilt is. Therefore there is no couple acting on the rod (or, equivalently, its centre of gravity stays above the fulcrum at all times). With no couple, the angular momentum of the rod must be constant, so if you let it go carefully giving it no angular velocity then it will remain in the same position.
If the rod has significant thickness then when it is tilted the weight of the part on the down slope side of the fulcrum is slightly greater than the weight of the part on the up slope side (equivalently, the rod's centre of gravity moves slightly away from the centre towards the down slope side of the rod). Now there is a couple acting on the rod that will tend to increase its angle of tilt. Even if you release it with no angular velocity, it will continue to tilt until it eventually slides off the fulcrum.
Oscillation requires a restoring couple that acts in the opposite sense to the angle of tilt. I cannot see any circumstance in which the rod can oscillate unless it is attached to the fulcrum in some way.

If the rod were perfectly homogenous, infinitely thin, placed on the fulcrum precisely at the midpoint, and the end released without imparting any motion, the rod would theoretically remain at rest in any position. That's because the sum of the forces and sum of the moments would be zero for any position.
However, for a rod of finite thickness, as the rod is rotated there will be  a net moment about the fulcrum of $mgr\sin\theta$, where $m$ is the mass of the rod, $r$ its radius, and $\theta$ the angle between the rod and the horizontal. This will result in angular acceleration. In addition, without friction at the fulcrum, the rod may slide down the fulcrum.
Hope this helps.


As can be seen in the above diagram, part (triangle defined by HCK) of the green half of the balance bar that was on the left when the bar was in equilibrium, is now on the right making the right half heavier when the bar is tilted to the right. The bar will therefore stay tilted to the right (so ChatGTP is wrong again). This obviously does not apply if the bar is infinitely thin, but a real balance bar has to have non zero thickness in order to able to support weights. This makes a straight balance bar inherently unstable at the balance position. In practice this instability is reduced in real scales by putting a slight bend in the balance bar and suspending the compared weights, below the bar.

